# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de la App en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Quiero cambiar el nombre de mi app (Siempre lo hago manual) pero esta vez me gustaría saber como hacerlo con la función de Laravel.

Al acceder a `config/app` hay una líne:

```
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
```

en dicha línea cambio Laravel por el nombre que le quiero dar a mi app, pero no pasa nada. Debo hacer algo adicional? o lo estoy haciendo mal.

Estoy usando Laravel 7 y no veo información en la documentación (A menos que haya buscado mal).

Comment: Después de cambiar el nombre en esa línea, recomiendan que uses estos comandos: `php artisan optimize`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan config:cache`. Tomado de [este tema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520118/how-to-rename-a-project-in-laravel-7)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo hago!

Comment: No, no funcionó... Es una instalación nueva de Laravel

Comment: Esto `env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel')` quiere decir que el nombre es el que tengas en la clave `APP_NAME` del archivo `.env`, o si no hay ninguna, por defecto que use `'Laravel'`. O sea, tienes que revisar el archivo `.env` y ver qué valor tiene esa clave `APP_NAME`

Comment: Gracias porloscerros, lo hice pero no cambió... Lo intentaré de nuevo pero esta vez con los comandos que dijo ANtonio a ver.

Comment: Excelente, cambiando en el archivo .env y luego ejecutando los dos últimos comando funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

simplemente
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel')
en esta linea cambia a
'name' => 'my proyect',
espero te sirva

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer en la consola con:

```
php artisan app:name NombreDeLaAPP
```

o lo puedes hacer manualmente en .env

```
APP_NAME='NombreDeLaAPP'
```

Luego haces restart de tu APP con

```
php artisan serve
```

Si no te funciona, prueba borrando la cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes cambiarlo en .env

```
APP_NAME=Nombre
```

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo `.env`, ubicado en la raiz del proyecto cambia la clave APP_NAME:

```
APP_NAME=Mi proyecto
...
```